# How do I add an on-premis Service Fabric cluster to Visual Studio 2017 Cloud Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

We are considering using stand-alone Service Fabric (not in Azure). I have a non-development cluster running for Test, but my application that works in my local box is returning 500 errors in the non-dev cluster. However, I don't see any way to add the Test cluster to Cloud Explorer. It only knows of local and Azure. How do I connect the Diagnostic Events Console to this other cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Explorer only supports clusters in Azure and a local dev cluster. We can show the local dev cluster because we have innate knowledge of how to find it. You can't add additional on-prem clusters.

Comment: But WHY can't we add additional on-prem clusters? I should be able to tell Visual Studio that I'm running a cluster on a certain machine and ClusterConnectionEndpoint port and protocol, and it should show up in the Cloud Explorer. What could be the reasoning behind not having this on day one? At worst, it should only need the config used to generate the cluster, and the machine name. I realize that logging in a cluster is more complex than a single machine, but how can it not be possible to have a built-in logging service in Service Fabric?

Comment: Cloud Explorer was built to provide developers with an easy way to browse their Azure resources from with Visual Studio. We do show local dev-specific resources like storage emulator and SF dev cluster since we know how to find and attach to those.